# How to handle promise rejection when using fromPromise (rxjs5.5)

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I couldn't find a way to handle promise rejection while writing following redux-observable epic. How can I handle `getDataFromPromise` rejection? I've tried pipe, catch, catchError etc.

```
(action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(request().type)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      fromPromise(getDataFromPromise(action.payload)).map(data =>
        success(data)
      )
    )
```

Following should be working according to [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html) example, but it doesn't.

```
(action$, store) =>
   action$.ofType(request().type).mergeMap(action =>
     fromPromise(getDataFromPromise(action.payload))
       .pipe(catchError(error => of(failure(error))))
       .map(data => success(data))
   )
```

Comment: you may need to provide the code for getDataFromPromise, I am unsure if the promise did reject

Comment: You may think like `new Promise((resolve,reject)=> reject())`. When promise resolved, no problem, it works, but catching, I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using RxJS v6, there is not such 'fromPromise' observable creation. Please see this post and answered by Ben Lesh:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3525

Instead, you should use `'from'` creation of observable.

Also, I suggest to have a quick look at the example of the redux-observable document which throw the light of using 'ajax' helper to handle error of observable from promise with `catchError` operator:
https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html?_sm_au_=isVnQCj8r4v4Z08F

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action => ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
    map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    catchError(error => of({
      type: FETCH_USER_REJECTED,
      payload: error.xhr.response,
      error: true
    }))
  ))
);
```

So an easier way to fix the code might just to follow this and use 'ajax' to wrap your getDataFromPromise function.

Comment: I'm using rxjs5.5, so I cant use it. About the request, it's not ajax, its some processing which could fail.